# How large would the Moon have to be such that I could not see it in its entirety from earth?

Tags: distance

The [^circumference of the] moon can be seen in its entirety from Earth [^during a full moon] taking up a very small portion of the visible sky. The Moon is ~1/4 the diameter of the Earth. If for the purpose of discussion the Moon's diameter were increased by ~4 times (while keeping the distance between the surface of the Earth and the moon the same as it is now); what would prevent me from seeing the whole Moon from Earth ... regardless of the math/physics equations?

Comment: I really can't see the entire (half) moon now.   I can see slightly less than half the moon.  for a larger moon, I'd see an even smaller fraction.  So your question is a matter of degree: what fraction of the moon shall I say corresponds to "not see it in its entirety".  I can't answer your question until I know that fraction.

Comment: I should have said circumference instead on entirety, sorry.Being a laywoman I was only discussing what can be seen with the naked eye say during a full moon not what may be visible anytime. I understand that we could fit ~50 moons inside of the Earth, but the visible circumference would only increase by ~4 times which should be entirely visible from Earth. I do not see how math/physics equations could change that.

Comment: even if the size were infinite it would never cover the entire sky, unless its shape were curved into surrounding the earth

Answer (score 1):

At any distance closer than infinity, you can't see an entire hemisphere.  The closer and larger it is, the less of the hemisphere is visible to you.

[image]

We can calculate how much of the hemisphere you cannot see.  The distance to the moon is approximately $3.84 \times 10^8$m, and it has a radius of around $1.74 \times 10^6$m.  Instead of being able to view a full 180 degrees, there will be some angle from the edge ($\theta$) that is out of view.

$\theta = \sin^{-1}(\frac{R}{L}) = 0.26 \, \text{degrees}$.  That's such a small amount, you can't really tell that you're not seeing an entire hemisphere.

Comment: Ok,  I apologize for my ill thought out question and of course you are correct. I will try to do better in the future. Thanks for bringing me back to reality hahaha.